# Why has this pattern formed in a photo of my laptop screen, and why does it vary from camera to camera?

Tags: visible-light, interference, diffraction

[image]

So I got these weird patterns when I photographed my laptop screen with a phone camera (Realme Narzo 10A). I thought they might have something to do with diffraction. Then, for some reason, when I zoomed in to the pic slightly, the pattern morphed into something else.

What exactly is happening here?

Also, I tried the same thing with an iPhone 12, and the picture there had very few to none of these lines. Why is this so? Is there anything you can conclude about the phone based on these lines?

Comment: @BowlOfRed to some extent yes. But I'd like to know why this varies from phone to phone, and if there's any information you can glean from the lines (for eg, I remember someone calculating the wavelength of light based on a diffraction pattern, something like that)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1814/

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Moiré pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern), it results from the lines in your camera not being perfectly aligned with the lines on the screen, and the different resolutions of the both.

Comment: By lines, do you mean the rows/columns of pixels @Yukterez?